# How to import kinect data?

Tags: import

I want to use kinect Data Import to import data of kinect to blender, then apply that to a model in blender with kinect data import add-on. I used [this](http://blender.vsb.cz/index.php/en/kinect-blender/installation-kinect)
link to get this done, but I have a problem understanding the last step:

> Now you have enable armature control using the Kinect data

Answer (score 1):

What he his doing there is **enabling an [addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Add-Ons)**. Do do this hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>, or *File>User Preferences*.

[image]

Now you are in the user preferences. Go to the addons tab. Next you will need to install the addon. Click *Install from File*.

[image]

Navigate to the addons .zip or .py, and select it.

The final thing to do is to select the checkbox. **If** you want the addon to be installed when you create a new project, click *Save User Settings*.